# Swift - Error passing data between protocols / delegates (found nil)

Tags: swift, null, delegates, protocols

I am developing an application with swift 3.0. Where what I want to do is, from the "MainMapVC" class, which is the view where you have a map with a date slider (see the attached image). I want to move the slider and send that slider position (1,2 or 3) to LeftSideViewController which is the side view (the legend) updating the content depending on the selected date.

**View of MainMapVC:**

[image]

**View of MainMapVC with Legend:**

[image]

Well, and I've come to the point where I have to pass a value between the two view controllers. But problem is that I get the error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value". Basically I have a "nil" delegate.

But do not find where the error is, because the definition of the delegate is like "var delegate: MainMapVCDelegate!" And I call it "delegate.moveSliderDates (datePos: Int (roundedValue))" in the "MainMapVC" class.

**Does anyone know where I failed in the statement of the delegate?Thanks :)**

I attach the code of the two classes so that you see the whole code.

**Class MainMapVC (first way):**

```
import UIKit

protocol MainMapVCDelegate: class {

    func moveSliderDates(datePos: Int)

}


class MainMapVC: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, GMSMapViewDelegate {

//MARK: VARIABLES
weak var delegate: MainMapVCDelegate? = nil


let step: Float = 1
@IBAction func moveSliderDates(_ sender: UISlider) {
    let roundedValue = round(sender.value / step) * step
    sender.value = roundedValue 
    delegate?.moveSliderDates(datePos: Int(roundedValue))      

}

}
```

**The delegate value inside the moveSliderDates function is "nil":**

```
delegate?.moveSliderDates(datePos: Int(roundedValue))
```

**Class LeftSideViewController (first way):**

```
import UIKit

class LeftSideViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, customCellDelegate, MainMapVCDelegate {

 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "MainMapVC" {
        let secondViewController = segue.destination as! MainMapVC
        secondViewController.delegate = self
    }
}

func moveSliderDates(datePos: Int){
    print(datePos)
    print("/////////////")
    tableSideLeft.reloadData()
}
```

**not enter inside this function because the delegate of "MainVC" is "nil":**

**Class MainMapVC (second way):**

```
 let step: Float = 1
 @IBAction func moveSliderDates(_ sender: UISlider) {
    let roundedValue = round(sender.value / step) * step
    sender.value = roundedValue

    let data:[String: Int] = ["data": Int(roundedValue)]
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "notificationName"), object: nil, userInfo: data)

}
```

**Class LeftSideViewController (second way):**

```
    func listnerFunction(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    if let data = notification.userInfo?["data"] as? String {
        print(data)
    }



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(listnerFunction(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "notificationName"), object: nil)
}
```

**Never goes into the function listnerFunction**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the error because you defined your delegate as force unwrapped noy-nil version by this code `var delegate: LeftSideDelegate!`

Instead, you need to change it like this. You should not create strong reference cycle for delegate.

```
weak var delegate: LeftSideDelegate? = nil
```

Then for all your delegate calles, do the wrapped version delegate call

```
delegate?.changeZindexDelivery()
```

Other than that, change your line `protocol LeftSideDelegate {` into `protocol LeftSideDelegate : class {`

**Passing data between view controllers using delegate**

First, in the class where you want to pass the data to another view controller, declare protocol in this way

```
protocol SampleDelegate: class {
    func delegateFunctionCall(data: String)
}
```

Then, create delegate variable as optional with type weak var. Call delegate method with you want to pass data or trigger action

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate: SampleDelegate? = nil

    @IBAction func sendTextBackButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        delegate?.delegateFunctionCall(data: textField.text!)

    }
}
```

Finally in your view controller that you want to receive action or data, implement the protocol. When you are initiating the second view controller, set it's delegate variable to be the current view controller

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, SampleDelegate {

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showSecondViewController" {
            let secondViewController = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
            secondViewController.delegate = self
        }
    }

    func delegateFunctionCall(data: String) {
        label.text = data
    }
}
```

**Passing data between view controllers using notification**

In the destination view controller, register a handler function that is ready to be called. You can add this registration code in view did load

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(listnerFunction(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "notificationName"), object: nil)

func listnerFunction(_ notification: NSNotification) {
    if let data = notification.userInfo?["data"] as? String {
        // do something with your data   
    }
}
```

Then in another view controller, if you want to pass data, simply call this

```
let data:[String: String] = ["data": "YourData"]
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "notificationName"), object: nil, userInfo: data)
```

Comment: Thanks @Fangming Ning! We are advancing :) ! Now there is no error "found nil", but the delegate variable in "delegate? .moveSliderDates (datePos: Int (roundedValue))" is still "nil" and I can not call the "moveSliderDates" function. Do you know why it can happen? 
I think I have to initialize the delegate, but I do not know how or where ... Thanks !

Comment: @JordiGallenRenau You are receiving this protocol call in extension, right? (`extension MainMapVC: LeftSideDelegate`) Put a break point inside and see if that get called. Btw what do you mean by saying you cannot call the moveSliderDates function? It gives you some error?

Comment: I have a protocol/delegate to pass a data (roundedValue, you can see it in the code) from "MainMapVC" to LeftSideViewController. But in the function "@IBAction func moveSliderDates (_ sender: UISlider)" when it arrives at the line "delegate? .moveSliderDates (datePos: Int (roundedValue)" "now no error appears (as it appeared before" found nil " ) But it also does not require passing "roundedValue" from the "MainClassVC" class to LeftSideViewController, because the delegate is "nil". I need it not to be "nil" to recognize that function that is in the other class.

Comment: I did not explain well, the thing is that there is no error in the application, the application does not crash, but if I put a breakpoint in "delegate? .moveSliderDates (datePos: Int (roundedValue))" the delegate value is "nil" and does not reach the "moveSliderDates" function that is defined in the other class.

Comment: @JordiGallenRenau Oh, so you need a prepare for segue method for your main view controller. The destination must be your left view controller. Then you need to do destinationViewController.delegate = self

Comment: Mmmmm ...Interesting! I think we are getting closer to the solution;)!
I have in LeftSideViewController this line "leftSide_vc = self.storyboard? .instantiateViewController (withIdentifier:" MainMapVC ") as! MainMapVC
        LeftSide_vc.delegate = self "and in MainMapVC I have this line" menu_vc = self.storyboard? .instantiateViewController (withIdentifier: "LeftSideViewController") as! LeftSideViewController
        Menu_vc.delegate = self". Let's say that the communication from Left to Main is OK !but not in the case of delegate?.moveSliderDates that is when it finds the delegate to nil

Comment: @JordiGallenRenau Are you still not able to get this to work? Are you not using segue? You want to pass data from main to left, so what you need is, on your left view controller, define protocol, create delegate variable and call method on it. Then on you maincontroller, set the main itself to be the delegate object of left view controller. I am **so so** confused by your view controller initiation code

Comment: Thanks @Fangming Ning Still does not work. But the solution, now is close. I'm not using "segue". Basically what I want is that when a user moves the slider of the MainMap class it gets an event to the moveSliderDate function, so that it reloads the legend with the appropriate cells for that date. That's why I use protocols/delegates.I have updated the code only showing the iteration of the protocol and the delegate. But it still does not work :( If you do not mind, edit the code as you would.Surely you know how to declare the delegate correctly now that the code is clean. Thanks :) !

Comment: @JordiGallenRenau I have updated two normal ways that data get passed between view controllers. If that helps, please mark it as correct as correct answer. Let me know if it still doesn't work

Comment: Good morning @Fangming Ning I have tried both possibilities but they have not worked for me :( In the first form I have to tell you that my communication is not by segue.I want is to move the slider but without opening the other viewController (but that the table is updated). The problem is the same as always when it arrives at the line delegate? .moveSliderDates the delegate is nil because the delegate is not initialized. And in the second form I add the handler in Left but he does not hear anything when I call him.I've updated the code.What do you propose? Thank you so much for your patience

Comment: Any idea @Fangming Ning ? I can't advance on my project :). 
I want to mark the post as finished thanks to you.

Comment: @JordiGallenRenau Are you trying to call the delegate method when your target view controller is not initialized yet? Both method only works when the source and target view controllers are valid

Comment: Many thanks @Fangming Ning !!
What do you mean with "are valids". I know I need to initialize the target view Left so the delegate is not nil But how do I do?
Because I thought it was initialized with in the destination class "LeftSide" the following lines: mainMap_vc = self.storyboard? .instantiateViewController (withIdentifier: "MainMapVC") as? MainMapVC
        MainMap_vc? .delegate = self "
Anyway, how would you do to pass the position of the slider from one class to the other? Thank you very much for your insistence, in the end we will get it :)! I just needthat delegate is not nil

Comment: @JordiGallenRenau Join the chat room